# “TypeError: null is not an object (Evaluating ‘RCTVideoInstance.Constants’)”

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video

I’m having a problem where I get this error: “TypeError: null is not an object (Evaluating ‘RCTVideoInstance.Constants’)” for the react-native-video library. I am trying it on an android. What can I do to solve this problem? I have also tried the manual installation but it didn't work. Also I have noticed that I get a similar problem with react-native-image-crop-picker. I'll be very grateful if somebody can help me.

Comment: Have you checked [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/1738)?

Comment: No. I just read it and I have already tried all does things and it still didn't work. I guess my best solution is to use the expo video library

Comment: Check with the version of third party using, and is it compatible with your react native version

Comment: Sorry I'm new in react native. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

`jcenter()` was removed in favor of `mavenCentral()` in `0.65`, add it back to `allprojects.repositories` and it'll magically work again in `android/build.gradle`.

Original Answer: https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/issues/2468#issuecomment-911368291

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue in android by adding this line in allprojects.repositories

> jcenter()

and for the IOS try to uninstall the app from the device/simulator and install using Xcode.
Hope its help :)